# "attempt to index nil with 'MoveDirection'"

Tags: lua, roblox

I am making a script which changes the footstep sound of the player but it keeps returning with the error message "attempt to index nil with 'MoveDirection'.

```
local runService = game:GetService("RunService")
local player = game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer
local character = player.Character or player.CharacterAdded:Wait()
local human = character:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")


runService.RenderStepped:Connect(function()
    if human.MoveDirection.Magnitude > 0 then -- walking
        game.SoundService.WalkingSound.Playing = true
    else -- if player not walking
        game.SoundService.WalkingSound.Playing = false
    end
end)
```

I have tried changing variables and double checking spelling, still returns back with an error message.

any help is appreciated.

Comment: It means `human` is nil. Guess the Humanoid wasn't found.

Answer (score 1):

Where is this script located in? if its not in somewhere runs every time the player dies (for example `StarterPlayer.StarterCharacterScripts`) your code wont work since the `humanoid` object attached to `human` variable no longer exists. (and you would get the `attempt to index nil with 'MoveDirection'` error)
or if its already in an place where the scripts in it runs everytime player dies try using :WaitForChild() instead of :FindFirstChild() at line 4

use this:

> local human = character:WaitForChild("Humanoid")

instead of this:

> local human = character:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")